# Google Play Music keeps putting non-music audio files into my music library

Tags: applications, samsung, music, google-play-music

So now all of my audiobooks and ring tones are in there with my songs and there's no way to seperate them even though I keep my music, audiobook and ringtones in separately files on my SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Move all of these non song files to a specific folder on your SD card, and create an empty file in that folder called ".nomedia". This tells Android not to scan for media there